# What’s the right way to offer public channels on PubNub?

Tags: pubnub

I have an application that serves multiple customers. As part of my workflow, I would like to use PubNub for realtime messaging to customers, offering something like one channel per customer. I would like to just give my customers a subscription key that they can use to listen to messages on their particular channel.

Is this a supported scenario on Pubnub? What’s the right way to set this up? I assume that I will do all the setup on my side and also handle all the billing, while just handing my customers the subscription keys to their channels. But for now, on my Pubnub account, I only see one “subscribe key”. I would like all keys and customer data to be isolated from one another.

Comment: Yes indeed this is a supported scenario  :-)  You can see the recommendations from Bhagat Nainani below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the PAM access manager feature for handling this. In addition to the subscribe key you will also provide your customers an auth-token. You can grant access to an auth-token to publish/subscribe to a specific set of channels. 
You can find more details here:
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/access-manager.html